# map function to change array values?

Tags: php, dictionary

I want to know if there is a map function or similar to use with array values? Say I have the following array..

```
$nums = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

I want to multiply these values by 5, changing the array values where my expected output would be.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 15
    ...... and so on
 )
```

Is there a function i can use to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, and it is called `array_map`:

```
$nums = array_map(function($number) { return $number * 5; }, $nums);
```

Or with `array_walk`:

```
array_walk($nums, function(&$number) { $number *= 5; });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily iterate over the array.

```
foreach ($nums as &$value) {
  $value *= 5;
}
```

A little more complicated, you can use `array_map()` as well.

```
array_map(function($x) { return $x * 5; }, $nums);
```

Comment: `foreach ($nums as $value) $nums[] = $value * 5;`? I don't think so.

Comment: `foreach ($nums as &$val) $val *= 5;`

Comment: Doing `$nums[] = $value * 5;` will append new values to the end of the array instead of changing them, perhaps it even loops ifinitely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific `map` function, but you can create your own using `array_map` or a foreach loop.

```
function map($n) {
   return $n*5;
}

$nums = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
print_r(array_map(map, $nums));
```

Or

```
function map($n, $array) {
   foreach ($array as &$val) {
      $val *= $n;
   }
   return $array;
}

$nums = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
print_r(map(5, $nums));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 15
    [3] => 20
    [4] => 25
    [5] => 30
    [6] => 35
    [7] => 40
    [8] => 45
    [9] => 50
)
```